# Is there a way to reverse a range of strings using a button instead of using a function?

Tags: excel, vba

I know there is a way to reverse strings in excel (and even this throws me a #NAME? error on the spreadsheet), but I do not want to call a function in the spreadsheet. I instead want to use a button to perform the action for me.

However, I can physically go in and and reverse one myself, but am unsure of the syntax (for this method) if I wanted to do this 4 other times. This will reverse the value I wanted and with a button press toggle it back to the original, however how would I go about doing this for other entries within the same range?

```
Private Sub btnReverse_Click()
Select Case btnReverse.Value
Case True
Sheet1.Range("D38:D41").Columns.Replace _
What:="iphone", Replacement:="enohpi" _

Case False
Sheet1.Range("D38:D41").Columns.Replace _
What:="enohpi", Replacement:="iphone" _
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[`StrReverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87)

```
Private Sub btnReverse_Click()
    For Each cell In [D38:D41]
        cell.Value = StrReverse(cell.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that is much easier than my method! I appreciate it tons.